# Can't sorting when use analyzer with solr

Tags: solr

I'm trying to use wildcard searching, and it worked, but sorting is not. 
My solr schema file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schema name="addressByFilters" version="1.5">
<types>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
</types>
<fields>
    <dynamicField indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="address*" type="TextField"/>
    <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="address_code" stored="true" type="TextField"/>
</fields>
</schema>
```

When I change my analyzer above by new analyzer, sorting is work, but wildcard search is not.

```
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="TextField">
<analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

My solr query is:

```
solr_query = ' { "q" : "address1:*Test\\ ace*", "sort" : "address_code asc", "start":"0", "useFieldCache":true }' limit 100;
```

How can I fix it? Thank you so much

Comment: Create two fields, both of them with the different analyzers and then use copyField to copy data onto another field. Then you can use one for the sorting and the another for wildcard search purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different fields for sorting and searching. This is in particular useful when you have situations like this, where the processing required for sorting is different from the processing required for searching.

[Use a `copyField` instruction](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/copying-fields.html) to get the same content into both fields.

```
<copyField source="address_code" dest="address_code_sort" />
```